# Check which number nearest to the value 0 among two given integers

Tags: c++, math

I have 2 integers:

```
int number1 = 45;
int number2 = 40;
```

Now I want to compare both and check which one is nearer to the number 0.

As output I want true / false.

For example:

```
if (compare(number1, number2))
{
    console.write("number1 is nearer to 0");
}
else
{
    console.write("number2 is nearer to 0");
}
```

Output:

> number 2 is nearer to 0

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How to code the function that calculates which of the integers is nearer to 0

Comment: if(abs(number1)<abs(number2))

Comment: I guess the output is correct, isn't it? You can use `std::abs` to make it work with -ve numbers. Other than that everything is right.

Comment: the one with smaller absolute value is closer to 0

Comment: Hint: `Min (|x| & |y|)`

Comment: C++ doesn't have a standard object named `console`, nor does it have a free function named `compare`. What language is this really?

Answer (score 0):

You shold use ABS, before compare.

Comment: Edge case: INT_MIN

Comment: then `absu()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the actual function 'compare', and that the integers can be negative

```
int compare(int number1, int number2) {
    return abs(number1) < abs(number2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for doing their homework for them. How are they going to learn?

Answer (score 0):

```
int compare(int a, int b)  {
    if (abs(a) > abs(b)){
        std::cout <<b <<" is closer to zero" <<std::endl ;
        return b;
    }
    else{
        std::cout <<a <<" is closer to zero" <<std::endl ;
        return a;
    }
}
```

This function might be helpful for you. It both displays the answer in the terminal and returns the int value which is closer to 0 in order to be used by other parts of your program.